# Sklearn's GroupShuffleSplit is yielding overlapping results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have used `GroupShuffleSplit` in the past and it has worked OK. But now I am trying to split based on a column and it's producing overlap between the test and train data. This is what I am running

```
val_inds, test_inds = next(GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=0.5,
                                           n_splits=2,).split(df, groups=df['cl_uid'].values))


df_val = df[df.index.isin(val_inds)]
df_test = df[df.index.isin(test_inds)]

# this value is not zero
len(set(df_val.cl_uid).intersection(set(df_test.cl_uid)))
```

Any idea what could be going on?

`sklearn` version 0.24.1 and `Python` version 3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return of `GroupShuffleSplit` is the **array indices** so if you want to split your DataFrame you should use `.iloc` to filter.

```
df_val = df.iloc[val_inds]
df_test = df.iloc[test_inds]
```

If you mistakenly try to use the `index` to filter, then you are assuming that you have a non-duplicated `RangeIndex` that begins at 0. If that is not the case this filtering is bound to fail.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

# DataFrame with a non-RangeIndex
df = pd.DataFrame({'clust_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]}, index=[1,2,1,2,1,2,3])

val_inds, test_inds = next(GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=0.5, n_splits=2,).split(df, groups=df['clust_id']))
```

##### Correct splitting

```
df_val = df.iloc[val_inds]
#   clust_id
#2         2
#1         2
#2         2
#3         2

df_test = df.iloc[test_inds]
#   clust_id
#1         1
#2         1
#1         1
```

##### Incorrect splitting, confuses index labels with array-position labels

```
df[df.index.isin(val_inds)]
#   clust_id
#3         2

df[df.index.isin(test_inds)]
#   clust_id
#1         1
#2         1
#1         1
#2         2
#1         2
#2         2
```